# How to parse and access the items in a json object while using Flask?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify
import requests
from app.test_blueprint import app


@app.route('/')
def index():

url = 'http://api.address'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

return render_template('index.html', data=data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I cant seem to be able to access the items within the keys in the dictionary thats created from the json response

```
<ul>
{% for key in data %}
<li>{{data[key].items}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: pls, show an example of response json

Comment: You probably don't want `.items` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this:

```
<ul>
{% for vlaue in data.values() %}
<li>{{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```